# Interpolate inside html attributes with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm building an application using Backbone.js, Underscore.js, HAML, and Coffeescript.

The problem I'm having is getting variables to interpolate inside of html element attributes.

```
<% _.each(collection.models, function(document) { %>
%tr
  %td
    %input{:type => 'checkbox', :name => "documents[]", :value => "<%= document.attributes.id %>"}
  %td <%= document.attributes.id %>
  %td <%= document.attributes.name %>

  <% } %>
<% }); %>
```

The object's values are displaying properly inside of the `<td>`, but not within the input's value attribute.

Is interpolation inside of an element's attributes possible? I was not able to find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not experienced in this area, but please have a look [here](https://github.com/9elements/haml-coffee) if this is what you need. It supports coffeescript in attributes.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with your code, but I have used interpolation with underscore templates.

Comment: The problem is with interpolation inside of html element attributes.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this problem is to use HAML's `:escape_attrs` option.

```
Haml::Engine.new(template, :escape_attrs => false).render
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using html_safe which is a method on String objects. This will escape the html characters in the variable statement (< for example) and will leave the intact for underscore to evaluate at runtime:

```
%input{:type => 'checkbox', :name => "documents[]", :value => "<%= document.attributes.id %>".html_safe}
```

(Tested on rails 3.0.13)

Comment: This isn't working on Rails 4.2.6, but I'm not sure why. I can put the same code outside an attribute value, and my `<` is not escaped, but inside the attribute value, it is.

Comment: What I mean is, [the documentation on html_safe](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) says `.html_safe` is equivalent to `raw()` but though it is in fact equivalent outside attribute values, when passed through the HAML template engine, it's not, inside attribute values. This is very mysterious.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't closing the function in the template properly ( try adding `<% }); %>` to the end of your template).

I'm not really familiar with HAML syntax but here's a simple example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr3LB/) using plain HTML and an underscore template. As you can see you can definitely use interpolation in middle of an elements attributes.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the complete code. I'm updating the question.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I see that they are successfully interpolating within an element's attributes.

Comment: Then perhaps the problem is with your HAML syntax, since if you look at the jsfiddle i linked to you can see that it correctly interpolates inside the checkbox's value attribute.

Comment: I missed this earlier; it appears that HAML is escaping the code inside of the element's attributes. According to the HAML documentation there is a non-haml helper that runs code in a non HAML context.

Comment: Then perhaps using a different style delimiters (for example mustache style) for underscore will help here's a [link](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) to underscore's documentation describing how to change the delimiters used for interpolation.