# HAML -> Backbone Template, Unescaping HTML Parameters

Tags: ruby, backbone.js, haml

I'm using HAML to generate templates for a Backbone.js app. I need to be able to insert `<%= blah %>` as an html attribute a la:

```
%a{:href => "myresources/<% id %>"} My Resource
```

and have it output

```
<a href='myresources/<%= id %>' >My Resource</a>
```

in the html template.  Unfortunately, HAML escapes the html parameters leaving me with

```
<a href='#myresources/&lt;%= id %&gt;'>My Resource</a>
```

According to the [HAML Reference](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#unescaping_html) the '!' operator can be used for unescaping strings, but not within the HTML attributes.

Also, I'd use plaintext to render the anchor tag, but since the anchor tag is the root for this particular view, I lose all of the benefits of using HAML.

Any help?

**Update**
I didn't mention, but I'm using LiveReload to actually watch my file system and run the haml compiler, and there was a setting in LiveReload to disable HTML escapes in tag attributes. < head slap >  If anyone else runs into this issue outside of LiveReload, you can also set the `:escape_attrs` option to false when configuring your HAML setup.

Comment: I'm not using Rails, only HAML so there's no html_safe method available here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure HAML to not escape tag attributes using the `escape_attrs` option in your HAML configuration.  See [HAML Options](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#options).

Comment: This is the best answer I've yet read, but it does open up security issues, etc.  Would be great to see one-off fixes to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using html_safe which is a method on String objects. This will escape the html characters in the variable statement (< for example) and will leave the intact for underscore to evaluate at runtime:

```
%a{:href => "myresources/<% id %>".html_safe} My Resource
```

Found on answer to [Interpolate inside html attributes with Underscore.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332389/interpolate-inside-html-attributes-with-underscore-js)