# Passing 'require' to haml guard

Tags: ruby, haml, guard

Manually compiling haml to html with requirement of external file is performed like so

```
haml --require .\stuff.rb  --require .\const.rb .\pages\exit.haml .\pages\exit.html
```

However, I wanted to switch to haml guard. Unfortunately I am unable to find correct flag to pass for it to work. I need something along the lines of:

```
guard :haml, haml_options: {require: './stuff.rb ./const.rb'}  do
  watch(/^.+(\.haml)$/)
end
```

The result:

> 14:19:19 - ERROR - HAML compilation of pages/exit.haml failed!
>   [#] Error: undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass

which shows that neither the method nor constants were included.

Any ideas?

edit:
I'm using Ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32] (Win10),  Haml 4.0.7.

Minimized example:

**test.haml**

```
!!!
%html
    %header
    %body
        %p
            =$BT_OK.html_safe
```

**const.rb**

```
$BT_OK      = "&#13;".html_safe
```

**helpers.rb**

```
class String
  def html_safe?
    defined?(@html_safe) && @html_safe
  end

  def html_safe
    @html_safe = true
    self
  end
end

require 'haml/helpers/xss_mods'
module Haml::Helpers
  include Haml::Helpers::XssMods
end
```

Output using command line `haml .\debug\test.haml .\debug\test.html -r .\const.rb -r .\helpers.rb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <header></header>
  <body>
    <p>
      &#13;
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Error when using matt's solution:

```
08:02:06 - ERROR - Invalid Guardfile, original error is:
> [#]
> [#] undefined method `html_escape' for module `Haml::Helpers',
> [#] backtrace:
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
> [#]   (dsl)> C
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the files as an array, ie. `require: ['./stuff.rb', './const.rb']`?

Comment: Yes, it still fails with the same error.

Comment: Which version of haml and which version of Ruby?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`guard-haml` runs Haml “in process”](https://github.com/guard/guard-haml/blob/v1.1.2/lib/guard/haml.rb#L62), so in order to have those files available in your Haml script you need to require them in your `Guardfile`. You’ll also need to require Haml first too, since your helpers refer to some on Haml’s modules:

```
require 'haml'
require './helpers'
require './const'
guard :haml do
  watch(/^.+(\.haml)$/)
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach produces `undefined method `html_escape' for module `Haml::Helpers',` error when launching guard. The code in ./stuff.rb is taken from top answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596659/unescaping-haml-in-an-attribute-hash . However, the constants like `$BT_OK = "&#13;" ` work fine unless I invoke the `html_safe` method.

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs I can’t reproduce your errors, I think you might have some other issue. You may need to add more details.

Comment: Added more details to the question.

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs I’ve managed to reproduced this now; you need to `require 'haml'` first since your helpers refer to Haml modules (or you could add `require 'haml'` to your `helpers.rb` file).

Comment: Indeed! Though one would think, that such module goes by definition with `guard-haml` (same as with console `haml`). Anyway, you rock.